# single condition multiple variable assignment sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can you assign more than one variable under a single condition in a select statement, like in Visual Basic:

```
If x=1 then
   y=2
   z=5
End If
```

I have lots of complicated conditions that I don't want to keep repeating, over and over.

I have SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's how you would do it in t-sql, which I assume is what you're using:

```
DECLARE @y INTEGER
DECLARE @z INTEGER

IF @x = 1
BEGIN
  SET @y=2
  SET @z=5
END
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26126) a SQL fiddle to see the above code in action.

Comment: Well, I was really trying to do this in a select statement, and by condition was not an integer test, but a lot of complicated logic.

Comment: You could always make functions for the "complicated logic" so you don't have to repeat the logic over and over again in your select statement.

Comment: I thought functions only returned scalars or tables?

Comment: The idea is that if you have a complicated piece of logic, in which the final result is a single value, you can factor that logic into a function, and call that function to get the value. Anyway, maybe you can add more detail to your question and ask more specifics, it will be easier to know what you need.

Comment: My error was in the use of the term 'variable'. I meant colums.

Comment: My error was in the use of the term 'variable'. I meant colums. I want to use ordinary programming syntax such as 'if x=1 then do; z=1;y=8', or 'if x=3 and y = 4 and z=6 then q=9 and then use 'if q=9 then whatever' in another conditional statment. In orther words, why can't I use normal these simple progamming conditional assignment statements with columns? Is there something that can allow me to do this?